# How to repackage an .ANE extension in Windows

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ane

I have an conflict in my flash project between my native extensions. Some java libraries are included in both ANES, so I cant publish the game(I receive an error ...library X is added). I search around the google. And I found that I need to remove duplicated libraries, and after that I need to repackage the ANE with adt. I never did that before and I never created an ANE extension. Can someone guide me to a good direction, and how can I repackage my ane?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSf00ab63af761f170-168f6f2a129378b935d-8000.html), [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt5.html) and [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ane-android-devices.html) I think that can help.

Comment: Man, thank you very much! Please add your answer and I will accept it. You did help me.

Comment: Glad that helped you, I put an answer.

Comment: @tziuka I'm trying to repackage the ANE after remove some jar file, do you have any experience to share? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For AIR native extension packaging, take a look on :

- [Packaging a native extension](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSf00ab63af761f170-168f6f2a129378b935d-8000.html).
- [Building a native extension for iOS and Android – Part 5: Building the ANE file](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt5.html).
- [Developing and using Adobe AIR native extensions for Android devices](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ane-android-devices.html).

Hope that can help.

Comment: do you know if is possible to repackage an ane witout having the swc file?

Comment: @tziuka Take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSf268776665d7970d-2482335412ffea65006-8000.html#WS412056e602857f203fc141d0130e782c0ee-8000). I think if you can extract library.swf from the swc file, so you can use it to repackage the ane.

Comment: @akmozo hi, in my case I repackage the ANE, so I don't have the swc, I've tried to package without -swc but it said "Invalid SWC".. can you help ? :)